# java - end to end encryption handshake

Tags: java, sockets, security, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to implement an end-to-end encryption chat client for learning purposes however I cannot seem to get the server and client to agree on eachother's public key.

As I understand, they both encrypt the information they're sending to eachother with eachother's public key and decrypt the messages they receive with their own private key, I beleive the issue I'm having is that I can't to synchronise the reception of eachother's public keys, what am I doing wrong?:

Client side:

```
   private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
            this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(this.connection.getOutputStream());
            this.output.flush();
            this.input = new ObjectInputStream(this.connection.getInputStream());
            this.output.writeObject(this.serverKey);
            this.output.flush();
            try {
                this.serverKey = (PublicKey) this.input.readObject();
                System.out.println("Server Key Received!");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.showMessage("\n Streams connected successfully \n", false);
        }
```

Server side:

```
private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
        this.output = new ObjectOutputStream(this.connection.getOutputStream());
        this.output.flush();
        this.input = new ObjectInputStream(this.connection.getInputStream());
        this.output.writeObject(clientKey);
        this.output.flush();

        try {
            this.clientKey = (PublicKey) this.input.readObject();
            System.out.println("Client Key Received!");
            this.showMessage("\n Connection streams setup succsessfully", false);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Typically my console only outputs one of the 'Key Received' console lines (usually the clients) and not the other's. How can I craft a handshake protocol to ensure they've both received eachother's keys?

`serverKey` and `clientKey` are each respectively the public key sent from the server and public key sent from the client.

The keys are initially autogenerated as a keyPair and the public key variable is overwritten with the public key from the connected party.

Comment: Should work. Are you sure this is the real code? Are you doing any other I/O on these streams? or sockets?

Comment: @EJP i have some send message IO occuring where i decrypt the contents but thats about it

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with this code.